# Custom attribute not found for my custom view in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to declare custom views in android studio for my custom view. but android studio keeps showing me this error

```
AAPT: error: attribute bubbleSize (aka com.first.myapplication:bubbleSize) not found.
```

Here's my code:

My Custom view, just the declaration:

```
package com.first.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.view.View

class Bubble(context: Context): View(context) {

}
```

attr.xml file where i'm defining my custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Bubble">
        <attr name="bubbleSize" format="enum">
            <enum name="small" value="10"/>
            <enum name="big" value="25"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

activity_main layout where i'm using my custom view and custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.first.myapplication.Bubble
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:bubbleSize="small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried to invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @ShaluTD I did many times, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move your `attr.xml` file from `xml` folder to the `res->values` folder and change the `XML` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Bubble">
        <attr name="bubbleSize" format="enum">
            <enum name="small" value="0"/>
            <enum name="big" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Its worked fine for me. where you placed attr.xml file?

Comment: In res/xml, isn't here where it should be?

Comment: No. It should be in res->values folder. Try if it works I will update my answer